# Numerical computation of $\log \int_a ^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ from $\log f(x)$?

Tags: reference-request, integration

I want a numerical method to evaluate:

$$\log \int_a ^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

when what I have is a numerical routine to evaluate $\log f(x)$. The problem is that if $f(x)$ takes very large or very small values, direct evaluation of $f(x)$ will lead to overflows/underflows. I am wondering if anyone has approached this numerical integration problem in general?

Note that even though $f(x)$ can be very small in some regions and very large in other regions, you can't just approximate the small values to zero, because if the region where $f(x)$ is very small is large enough, it may contribute significantly to the integral.

Comment: If $f$ does not vary too much, you can try to normalize it by just one (or a couple) of its values: pick a point $x_1$ and compute $\log f(x_1) + \log\int e^{\log f(x)-\log f(x_1)}\,dx$. That might be enough avoid over-/underflows in the exponentials, depending on how the function behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You say that $f(x)$ has both very large and very small (positive) values. Then the integral you have is "large", and the small values of $f(x)$ don't matter very much: in those areas where $f(x)$ would produce an underflow, you might as well add zeros because the contributions of this to the overall integral do not matter.

So what matters are those areas where $f(x)$ is so large that you get overflows. This must happen because you have some kind of singularity at these locations. If so, it would be worth splitting $f(x)$ into its singular and non-singular parts and integrating the singular parts analytically if possible, and the remainder term with quadrature.

Comment: I did not say that $f(x)$ takes *both* very large and very small values. I said it takes very small values *or* very large values. These are two separate situations.

Comment: Ah, I read the statement that for different values of $x$, $f(x)$ may be large or small. Are you saying that it is *always* large, or *always* small?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: In that case, can't you just normalize $f(x)$ by dividing it by a "typical size"?

Comment: Ok. What if $f(x)$ is *very* large in a small region, and *very* small in a large region. In this case, both regions are important.

Comment: Yes. We can go on forever with this, though. It would be more productive if you state what you know about $f(x)$ in the question.

Comment: I added a paragraph to the question.

Comment: But what do you *know* about the function? Where does it come from? What is its shape? Etc.